# Spring web service client cannot start

Tags: spring, jaxb2, webservicetemplate

I am using spring web services to consume some soap web services. It has been working ok until I added a new package into my marshaller, unmarshaller beans.

```
<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller" >
   <property name="contextPaths">
       <list>
           <value>package1</value>
           <value>package2</value>
           <value>package3</value>
           <value>package4</value>
           <value>package5</value>
           <value>package6</value>
           <value>package7</value>
       </list>
   </property>
</bean>
<bean id="unmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller" >
  <property name="contextPaths">
  <list>
      <value>package1</value>
      <value>package2</value>
      <value>package3</value>
      <value>package4</value>
      <value>package5</value>
      <value>package6</value>
      <value>package7</value>
  </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

When I added package7 and my application web application starts(it starts in wildly server) , I get the following exception. If I remove 'packaage7' , exception is gone.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'marshaller' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't parse argument number: ''{0}''
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
... 74 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't parse argument number: ''{0}''
at java.text.MessageFormat.makeFormat(MessageFormat.java:1429) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at java.text.MessageFormat.applyPattern(MessageFormat.java:479) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at java.text.MessageFormat.<init>(MessageFormat.java:362) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:840) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.Messages.format(Messages.java:133)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeInfoSetImpl.add(TypeInfoSetImpl.java:306)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RegistryInfoImpl.<init>(RegistryInfoImpl.java:121)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.addRegistry(ModelBuilder.java:362)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:332)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:460)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:298)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:141)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1163)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:145)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:236)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:137) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:294) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:412) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:375) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.createJaxbContextFromContextPath(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:486)
at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.getJaxbContext(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:453)
at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.afterPropertiesSet(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:435)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
... 81 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "''{0}''"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
at java.text.MessageFormat.makeFormat(MessageFormat.java:1427) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
... 108 more
```

When I configure the marshallers with only 'package7' I dont get the stacktrace, but this does not work for me , as I need the other packages.
I guess there is a conflict with the classes, but I cannot figure out what it is , and the excepcion does help much

Does anyone have any clue what could be happenning ?

UPDATE::
I think this issue is related with there are some namespaces which are shared across the different packages but they are generated in each one of them. I supect on some .NET types:

```
private final static QName _AnyType_QNAME = new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/", "anyType");
private final static QName _AnyURI_QNAME = new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/", "anyURI");
private final static QName _Base64Binary_QNAME = new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/", "base64Binary");
private final static QName _Boolean_QNAME = new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/", "boolean");
private final static QName _Byte_QNAME = new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/", "byte");
private final static QName _DateTime_QNAME = new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/", "dateTime");
private final static QName _Decimal_QNAME = new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/", "decimal");
private final static QName _Double_QNAME = new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/", "double");
private final static QName _Float_QNAME = new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/", "float");
private final static QName _Int_QNAME = new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/", "int");
private final static QName _Long_QNAME = new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/", "long");
private final static QName _QName_QNAME = new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/", "QName");
private final static QName _Short_QNAME = new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/", "short");
private final static QName _String_QNAME = new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/", "string");
private final static QName _UnsignedByte_QNAME = new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/", "unsignedByte");
private final static QName _UnsignedInt_QNAME = new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/", "unsignedInt");
private final static QName _UnsignedLong_QNAME = new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/", "unsignedLong");
private final static QName _UnsignedShort_QNAME = new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/", "unsignedShort");
private final static QName _Char_QNAME = new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/", "char");
private final static QName _Duration_QNAME = new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/", "duration");
private final static QName _Guid_QNAME = new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/", "guid");
```

Comment: Has anyone experienced something similar ?

Comment: I think this issue is related with some namespaces which are shared across several web services.  I edited the post to have more information

Answer (score 0):

organize wsimport package by soapaction:

My case:

```java
UsuariosamPleSampleAPISv1_1.wsdl
UsuariosamPleSampleAPISv1.xsd
UsuariosamPleSampleAPISv1_1.xsd
UsuariosamPleSampleAPISv1_1_2.xsd
UsuariosamPleSampleAPISv1_1_2_3.xsd
UsuariosamPleSampleAPISv1_1_2_3_4.xsd
UsuariosamPleSampleAPISv1_1_2_3_4_5.xsd
UsuariosamPleSampleAPISv1_1_2_3_4_5_6.xsd
UsuariosamPleSampleAPISv1_1_2_3_4_5_6_7.xsd
UsuariosamPleSampleAPISv1_1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8.xsd
ServicesaMpleAPISv1.xsd
ServicesaMpleAPISv1_1.xsd
ServicesaMpleAPISv1_1.wsdl
ServicesaMpleAPISv1_1_2.xsd
ServicesaMpleAPISv1_1_2_3.xsd
ServicesaMpleAPISv1_1_2_3_4.xsd
ServicesaMpleAPISv1_1_2_3_4_5.xsd
ServicesaMpleAPISv1_1_2_3_4_5_6.xsd
ServicesaMpleAPISv1_1_2_3_4_5_6_7.xsd
ServicesaMpleAPISv1_1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8.xsd
```

¬¬  ¬¬  ¬¬

```java
@Configuration
public class ClientsConfiguration extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

  @Bean(name = "marshallerpackage1")
  public Jaxb2Marshaller marshallerpackage1() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    String[] paquetesBase = new String[] { "package1" };
    // error can't parse argument number: ''{0}'' --- new String[] { "package1","package2" };
    marshaller.setPackagesToScan(paquetesBase);
    return marshaller;
  }

  @Bean(name = "templatepackage1")
  public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplatepackage1() {
    WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
    webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshallerpackage1());
    webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(marshallerpackage1());

    return webServiceTemplate;
  }

  @Bean(name = "marshallerpackage2")
  public Jaxb2Marshaller marshallerBpackage2() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    String[] paquetesBase = new String[] { "package2" };
    marshaller.setPackagesToScan(paquetesBase);
    return marshaller;
  }

  @Bean(name = "templatepackage2")
  public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplatepackage2() {
    WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
    webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshallerBpackage2());
    webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(marshallerBpackage2());

    return webServiceTemplate;
  }

}
```

client side:

```java
@Service
public class wsClientServiceWs extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {


  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("marshallerpackage1")
  private Jaxb2Marshaller marshallerpackage1;
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("templatepackage1")
  WebServiceTemplate templatepackage1;
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("marshallerpackage2")
  private Jaxb2Marshaller marshallerpackage2;
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("templatepackage2")
  WebServiceTemplate templatepackage2;



  try {
      templatepackage1.setDefaultUri("http://localhost:8080/wsdl1");
      response1 = templatepackage1.marshalSendAndReceive(rq, "soapaction1"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("error Ws soap {}", e.getMessage());
    }




  try {
      templatepackage2.setDefaultUri("http://localhost:8080/wsdl1");
      response2 = templatepackage2.marshalSendAndReceive(rq, "soapaction2"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("error Ws soap {}", e.getMessage());
    }
```